# How to prevent that a lease is used twice in a distributed systems

Tags: distributed, distributed-system

I was wondering if it is possible to prevent that a lease is used twice.

**What is a lease?**

A lease is some sort of token that is given out to exactly one node at a time in a distributed setting. An example use case of a lease would be that only one node at the time can write to a database.

**What is a fencing token and why use it?**

With the lease as described above, we could run into problems. A node could stop (e.g. because of stop-the-world garbage collection) and still believe that his lease is valid, when in fact it is not. If we give each lease a fencing token (an incremental integer) the database could reject leases that uses old fencing tokens.

**My problem:**

Image [taken from Designing Data-Intensive Applications, p. 303](http://puhonua.com/docs/DDIA.pdf)

[image: taken from Designing Data-Intensive Applications, p. 303]

Here client 1 gets rejected, because he is using an old fencing token. But this is ONLY because client 2 used his token before client 1 and the store is aware that the current fencing token was incremented. **How can we make sure that client 1 would be rejected, when using an outdated lease, even if he tries to write before client 2 tries to write?**

Comment: give each token a lifespan an check if it's still valid when it is being used. Don't know if it's possible but that's just an idea.

Comment: @ElieNassif Thank you very much for the idea. I think this will not be possible here. The timing of each node is unreliable. Client 2 in this example experiences a stop-the-world process. His clock will stop. He cannot know that his token is outdated. Something like this could also happen to the store. So I would not know how it is possible to give the leases a live span.

Comment: maybe have a master slave system in place in charge of handling the tokens. The master is in charge of the lifespan, so when the client token expires, the master either informs the client about the event. hence the master is in charge of managing the tokens, the client just complies.

Comment: Maybe that could work. We would still have the problem like above, though. Client 2 is out. Master thinks he is dead. Master will no longer communicate with Client 2 anymore. Client 2 "wakes up" and thinks his token is still valid.

Comment: not if the master stores the token lifespan end time on his end, the time is relative to his own clock not the clients'

Comment: But then how does the store know that the token is still valid? Would he have to communicate with the master all the time and try to be at sync with his time? Or would the master have to be equivalent with the store?

Comment: The master calls the store when a new token is created (stores the time). when receiving a token from a client, the master communicates again with the store which responds with the token info, then the master performs the checking locally.

Comment: @ElieNassif Might be a valid solution... Not really sure if there a not some edge cases where this breaks

Comment: if the master goes down... then you should have perhaps a backup master that can continue in its' place, same for the store.

Comment: Please only one master. If you have multiple masters you have the problem of coordinating between masters. This will make everything much worse

Comment: This would require in depth investigation from your end.

Comment: Might be. Thank you very much for the suggestions so far @ElieNassif